# Error When Running VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I am Trying to run this code but it keeps giving me an error message while compiling

> Argument not optional

I am using a function called `csvRange`

```
Sub CS()
csvRange()
End Sub
Function csvRange(FirstNum, SecondNum) As Double
    i As Integer
    For i = FirstNum.Value To SecondNum.Value
            csvRange = csvRange & i & "+"
          Next        
End Function
```

can anyone help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that? `csvRange` just outputs a string like `3+4+5+6+7+8+9` if provided with the numbers 3 and 9. So what kind of string do you need?

Comment: You miss parameters for `FirstNum` and `SeconNum`. And you'll get next error with return value type. The function return double but return value is string.

Comment: Hi @afeefkhateeb, did you find any answer useful? It is always good to give feedback / rate answers.

Answer (score 0):

you want to call csvRange() but csvRange requires 2 arguments to pass.
And you forgot to save the return value.

for example

```
Sub CS()
var first = 1
var second = 50
var result
result = csvRange(first, second)
End Sub
Function csvRange(FirstNum, SecondNum) As Double
    i As Integer
    For i = FirstNum.Value To SecondNum.Value
            csvRange = csvRange & i & "+"
          Next        
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of remarks:
 - You call the function csvrange without parametervalues which you did not define as being optional.
 - You do nothing with the value the function returns
 - the i is an integer and the result a double. it is bad practice to mix them both in your for-next loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires a few fixes:
1) Use appropriate arguments for `csvRange`.
2) Use the return value of `csvRange` for something (this is not mandatory, but typically required in well designed code).
3) Declare the type of arguments for `csvRange`.
4) You seem to be using `csvRange` to get a `String`. Change code accordingly.

You would use something like

```
Sub CS()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = ...
    Set rng2 = ...
    Set retval As String
    retval = csvRange(rng1, rng2)
End Sub

Function csvRange(FirstNum As Range, SecondNum As Range) As String
    i As Integer
    csvRange = ""
    For i = FirstNum.Value To SecondNum.Value
         csvRange = csvRange & Cstr(i) & "+"
    Next i
End Function
```

PS1: Your output will end with a trailing "`+`". Perhaps this is not what you want.

PS2: I do not have a system to test this code.